# What is right way to build DB correctly?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have following atributes

Auto Mechanic(id,name,mech_type,work_type,work_price)

For example:(1,John,body repair,spoiler replacement,100$)

I divided it by the tables like this

1. Car Mechanic (mech_id,mech_name)
2. Mechqual(mechqual_id,mech_id,mechtype_id)
3. mechtype(mechtype_id,mechtype_name)
4. Work(work_id,car_id,mech_id,work_type,work_price)
   So mech-mechqual is M-M and mechqual-worktype  1-M.

But I think that`s not good, because you can write work_type that is not linked with mechtype of mechanic.

For example: mechqaul - brake technicians work_type - car painting.
What I should change? How to avoid incorrect fill of DB?

Comment: Hi. What info modeling & DB design reference/textbook are you following? If you are not following one, you need to find one, because you are asking us to write one.

Comment: The names got a bit confused. Is auto_id = car_id? mechtype_id = work_type? Please be consitent in your naming, so we can follow.

Comment: Can an auto mechanic, say John, do several types of work, i.e. body repair and car painting? Or is it one work type per mechanic?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, they can

Comment: @philipxy So we have next entities (client,car,mechanic,specializations,work)
Client can have many cars(1-M)
Mechanic has many specializations(M-M)
and specializations have many worktypes but i didnt allocated it as entity
also i think that many mechs can to work on 1 car(differnet works)
I ask about can i build DB that i can put the worktype by the list in PhpMyAdmin and not to check how i fill previous tables

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks! I will try this.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks for attention! I think we found the solution

Comment: Hi. You have given some info relevant to designing a solution. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. But please read my last comment again. You have not answered my question re what method you are following. "How to avoid" is, follow a design method. But here, to avoid "work_type that is not linked with mechtype of mechanic" in SQL declaratively you must add a table MechWork to say what mech_type can do what work_type and have Work FKs (mech_id,mech_type) to Mechanic & (mech_type,work_type) to MechWork. You don't need to add ids everywhere; a type identifies itself.

Comment: Even before finishing the schema, you should start trying to write the `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the names for readability. I think the situation is as follows:

```
table(columns)                                    | sample content
--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
worktype (worktype_id, name)`                     | 1/'body repair' , 2/'car painting'
workpart (workpart_id, worktype_id, name)         | 100/1/'spoiler replacement', 200/2/'partial painting'
mechanic (mechanic_id, name)                      | 123/'John'
ability  (mechanic_id, worktype_id)               | 123/1, 123/2
workdone (mechanic_id, workpart_id, price, car_id | 123/100/90$/4444
```

and you are worried, because with this model the DBMS cannot prevent workdones on workparts the mechanic has no ability for.

This is due to the fact that this datamodel is purely based on single technical IDs which has this drawback not to guarantee consistency in hierarchies.

If you'd use composite keys instead:

```
table(columns)                                                 | sample content
---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
worktype (worktype_no, name)`                                  | 1/'body repair' , 2/'car painting'
workpart (worktype_no, workpart_no, name)                      | 1/1/'spoiler replacement', 2/1/'partial painting'
mechanic (mechanic_no, name)                                   | 123/'John'
ability  (mechanic_no, worktype_no)                            | 123/1, 123/2
workdone (mechanic_no, worktype_no, workpart_no, price, car_no | 123/1/1/90$/4444
```

The workpart's primary key now is `worktype_no` + `workpart_no`. So a `workpart_no` without a `worktype_no` has no meaning. Only the combination tells you which workpart. Accordingly the workdone table contains both `worktype_no` and `workpart_no` in order to say what this work was about. And now you can have a constraint to the ability table. Problem solved.

You also mention, that this is about clients. Clients have cars and mechanics. Again the problem that a mechanic should only repair cars that belong to their client. And the solution is the same: A mechanic would have PK `client_no` + `machanic_no` and a `mechanic_no` alone would no longer have a meaning. Same for cars. And once more the workdone table would contain all the information that is needed to build proper foreign key constraints that prevent from inconsistencies.

**Conclusion:** It is not wrong to build a database on single technical IDs. This method is easy to use and widespread. But it does have the drawback of not guaranteeing consistancy over multiple levels (hierarchie). This is why I usually prefer to build a database on composite keys, although (or maybe because) it takes a bit longer to decide for the correct keys and build the database.